# Upload pdf using ajax and servlet

Tags: ajax, pdf, servlets

How can I upload pdf file using ajax without ?

I want upload the file, store the byte stream of that file in javascript variable using "JSON.stringify",
I want fetch that byte stream in servlet by using Gson and store that in an object(POJO) and write that byte stream using Fileoutputstream.write.

Is it really possible? In my jsp there is no form has been used, only table has been used to show row wise data including file upload. That page is for approval process of some data

Comment: You forgot to tell how the PDF file is selected/created. Are you using `<input type="file">` for that or?

Comment: Yes I am using <input type="file">. In my jsp there is no <form>. Beside <input type="file"> there are other elements as well.